# eigenvalues of block Tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a code in Matlab or any other program which can calculate all possible eigenvalues for a block Tridiagonal matrix of size 1000 or more,  I have tried a routine in Matlab with eigs but it seems to me there are many hidden eigenvalues that are not calculated.. appreciate any help:)

Comment: could you provide your code? what have you tried to do?

Comment: the `eig(A)` [command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) "returns a column vector containing the eigenvalues of square matrix"